# NodeJS EventEmitter with TypeScript class

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, typescript1.6

Is it possible to use NodeJS' `events.EventEmitter` with a TypeScript class? If yes, how?

I've tried countless variations in the last hours to get this working, so I won't list any of them.

What I basically want to do:

```
export class Database{
    constructor(cfg:IDatabaseConfiguration) {
        // events.EventEmitter.call(this); 
        mongoose.connect(cfg.getConnectionString(), cfg.getCredentials(), function (err:any) {
            if (err)
                this.emit('error', err);
            else
                this.emit('ready');
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: For a good solution, see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63649104/typesafe-listeners-using-eventemitter-and-typescript-in-node-js

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You should download node typings:

```
$ tsd install node --save
```

and then just use the following code:

```
///<reference path="./typings/node/node.d.ts" />
import events = require('events');

class Database{
    constructor() {
        events.EventEmitter.call(this);
    }
}
```

I simplified it to test your main problem.

**Edit:** Modified based on your comment:

```
///<reference path="./typings/node/node.d.ts" />
import events = require('events');

class Database extends events.EventEmitter {
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.emit('ready');
    }
}

new Database();
```

Comment: But I kinda need to extend the class, so that I can use `.on()` etc on my instance, right? `error TS2339: Property 'on' does not exist on type 'Database'.`

Comment: This works in your version, but not in my callback. I'm not very comfortable with OOP JS. So I added  `var that = this;` and used `that.emit` in my callback which works - I guess that's fine

Comment: Yes, to make it work with `this`, you can just change `function (err:any)` to `(err:any) =>` (arrow function). Arrow functions preserve `this` context.

Answer (score 31):

New approach:

```
///<reference path="./typings/node/node.d.ts" />

import {EventEmitter} from 'events';

class Database extends EventEmitter {
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.emit('ready');
    }
}

new Database();
```

Answer (score 5):

The modern way to download types definitions for NodeJS and EventEmitter particularly is:

```
npm install @types/node
```

or with yarn:

```
yarn add @types/node
```

Comment: and then `import { EventEmitter } from 'events'`