# Typesafe listeners using EventEmitter and Typescript in Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, eventemitter

Given a [Typescript](https://www.typescriptlang.org/) interface and a class extending [Node.js](https://nodejs.org/) [EventEmitter](https://nodejs.org/api/events.html#events_class_eventemitter), is it possible to define custom listeners that give typesafe check for the function arguments?

Given the following example:

```js
import { EventEmitter } from 'events';

interface Payload {
    id: string;
    weight: number;
}

class CustomEventEmitter extends EventEmitter {
    constructor() {
        super();

        this.on('my_event', (data) => {
            // I would like data to be implicitly inferred as Payload type
            console.log(data.weight); // This should compile
            console.log(data.something); // This should not compile
        });
    }
}
```

A node EventEmitter listener is defined as `(...args: any[]) => void)`, I would like to override the `any[]` type and use custom defined types instead. Is it possible?

Comment: Take a look at basarat's TypeScript Handbook, where he goes over a [Typesafe Event Emitter](https://basarat.gitbook.io/typescript/main-1/typed-event). I'm surprised that (or the library mentioned in the answer) didn't come up in your search...

Comment: Check out https://github.com/sindresorhus/emittery

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yep, there's an awesome package called [Typed-Emitter (link to project)](https://github.com/andywer/typed-emitter) that works really well for me.

From their docs:

```js
import {EventEmitter} from "events" // I made a slight change here as I've needed to explicitly import EventEmitter from events
import TypedEmitter from "typed-emitter"

// Define your emitter's types like that:
// Key: Event name; Value: Listener function signature
interface MessageEvents {
  error: (error: Error) => void,
  message: (body: string, from: string) => void
}

const messageEmitter = new EventEmitter() as TypedEmitter<MessageEvents>

// Good 
messageEmitter.emit("message", "Hi there!", "no-reply@test.com")

// TypeScript will catch those mistakes ✋
messageEmitter.emit("mail", "Hi there!", "no-reply@test.com")
messageEmitter.emit("message", "Hi there!", true)

// Good 
messageEmitter.on("error", (error: Error) => { /* ... */ })

// TypeScript will catch those mistakes ✋
messageEmitter.on("error", (error: string) => { /* ... */ })
messageEmitter.on("failure", (error: Error) => { /* ... */ })
```

```js
class MyEventEmitter extends (EventEmitter as new () => TypedEmitter<MyEvents>) {
  // ...
}
```

For your example, this should work:

```js
import { EventEmitter } from 'events';
import TypedEmitter from "typed-emitter"

interface Payload {
    id: string;
    weight: number;
}

interface CustomEventEmitterEvents {
  my_event: (data: Payload) => void
}

class CustomEventEmitter extends (EventEmitter as new () => TypedEmitter<CustomEventEmitterEvents>) {
    constructor() {
        super();

        this.on('my_event', (data) => {
            // I would like data to be implicitly inferred as Payload type
            console.log(data.weight); // This should compile
            console.log(data.something); // This should not compile
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Awesome, I've missed this library. Thanks!